# Observable undefined on the first page load - both working and non-working implementations provided, looking for the reason

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angularfire

**I am calling loadUserData() in the service constructor**. But the related observable is not defined, when the page is loaded for the first time. However, when I call the load function explicitly from the component, it works. **Please see the two implementations in** `ngOnInit()` in the component.ts file. This service is provided using `ModuleWithProviders` interface with a static `forRoot()` in the app.module.ts. *If I manually navigate away and then come back to this page, the `resumeData$` obervable works. and I don't have to call loadUserdata() from the component.ts file.* 
What am I missing here ?

**Load data service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { User } from '../model/user.model';
import { ResumeData } from '../model/resumeData.model';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { convertSnaps } from './db-utils';
import { Summary } from '../model/summary.model';
import { Category } from '../model/skill.model';
import { Education } from '../model/education.model';
import { CoreCompetency } from '../model/competency.model';

@Injectable()
export class LoadFirestoreDataService {
  user: firebase.User | null;
  summaryList$: Observable<Summary[]>;
  categoryList$: Observable<Category[]>;
  educationList$: Observable<Education[]>;
  coreCompetencyList$: Observable<CoreCompetency[]>;
  resumeData$: Observable<ResumeData[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.loadUserData();
      } else {
        this.user = null;
      }
    });
  }

  loadUserData(): Observable<ResumeData[]> {
    // console.log(this.user);
    const user = <User>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    // console.log(userId);
    // if (user.uid) {
    this.resumeData$ = this.db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('userData')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(snaps => convertSnaps<ResumeData>(snaps)));

    return this.resumeData$;
  }
}
```

A component.ts  file

```
  ngOnInit() {
// Following does not work
    this.dataService.resumeData$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
// Following works 
    this.dataService.loadUserData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

  }
```

**Edits:** 
Well just found out that the even after successful authentication loadUserData() was not being called from the constructor(). Now looking for why that was.

This code snippet was further developed into the following more readable form:

```
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.loadUserData();
  }

  loadUserData(): void {
    const user = <User>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));


    this.resumeData$ = this.db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('userData')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(snaps => {
          return convertSnaps<ResumeData>(snaps)[0];
        })
      );

    this.summaryList$ = this.resumeData$.pipe(pluck('summaryList'));
    this.educationList$ = this.resumeData$.pipe(pluck('educationList'));
    this.categoryList$ = this.resumeData$.pipe(pluck('categoryList'));
    this.coreCompetencyList$ = this.resumeData$.pipe(pluck('coreCompetencyList'));
  }
```

and the component.ts file is following:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.summaryList$ = this.dataService.summaryList$;

  }
```

subscription wan done using the async pipe:

```
        <div *ngFor="let item of (summaryList$ | async) as summaryList; let i = index">
          <app-summary-item [item]="item" [itemIndex]="i"></app-summary-item>
        </div>
```

Comment: As far as I can see,  `resumeData$` is **defined only** when `loadUserData()` is called. So, you could also do this inside `ngOnInit`: `this.service.loadUserData()` and on the next line `this.service.resumeData$.subscribe(...)` and everything should be working fine.

Comment: You may use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of an `Observable` ?

Comment: Noob here. Looking into behaviour subjects.

Answer (score 0):

`loadUserData()` function returns an `Observable`, which does absolutely nothing without calling `subscribe()` method on it. In your working code snippet you indeed subscribe to it:

```
// Following works 
this.dataService.loadUserData().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

while in you non-working code you just listen to `resumeData$` emits (but your constructor only executes function `this.loadUserData()` without subscribing to its returned `Observable`):

```
// Following does not work
this.dataService.resumeData$.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

So, in order to fix, just try to subscribe within your constructor:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if (user) {
      this.user = user;
      this.loadUserData().subscribe(); // <------- NEEDED CHANGE
    } else {
      this.user = null;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: "while in you non-working code you just listen to resumeData$ emits (but your constructor only executes function this.loadUserData() without subscribing to its returned Observable)" ------ Understanding this better ----do you mean that `this.loadUserData()` will not even return the observable to which I can subscribe later ?

Comment: You may not be correct. Because I am still able to do this without subscribing in the constructor. Please see my edits. I read somewhere that I should about manual subscriptions and use `async` pipes to prevent memory leaks. So I moved the code in that direction

Comment: Please see my edits. I believe that there was something wrong in the if block that subscribed to the authState. I removed that logic from this service, since I planned to use canActivate guards in future, then everything worked.

Comment: @mozpider, you are correct (and I am wrong), actually your `loadUserData()` function populates `resumeData$` to which you try to subscribe later. So, my only hint for you non-working code that for some reason `loadUserData()` is probably not called at all... Did you try to debug the flow? Which Angular are you using? Since 6.0 you can use `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' ,})` instead of static `forRoot()` function solution. Any way, please try to create a stackblitz (with mocked / simulated data) and I will try to help you there